# Laravel 5: generate:scaffold not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, way-generators

php artisan generate:scaffold not working at all. Its throwing error after:$ php artisan generate:scaffold {resource}

Do you want me to create a {resource} model? [yes|no] yes

[InvalidArgumentException] The "--templatePath" option requires a value.

But in the list of options after executing php artisan generate:scaffold --help there is no --templatePath And again if I try with php artisan generate:scaffold {resource} --templatePath

[RuntimeException]
The "--templatePath" option does not exist.

Comment: You're presumably using the L4 version. Most of it isn't necessary. What still is is found in a new package. https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended

Comment: @ceejayoz I am using Laravel 5

Comment: `generate:scaffold` doesn't appear to be in the L5 version.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `crud-generator` component to your `composer.json` then update your composer.

Follow origin guide: https://github.com/abmti/crud-generator